# How to send data from node.js to angular.js controller

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm using node.js and passport for authentication, and I need to send 'login failed' message to the client if a user failed to authenticate. My application uses also express middleware.
I'm using angular.js in the client.

Currently I'm using that command to show a static html:

```
var loginStatus = 'Failed';
res.sendfile('views/login.html'); // What should I add/change here in order to send the loginStatus variable ?
```

And this is my angular.js controller:

```
function MainController($scope) {
   $scope.loginStatus = // What should I write here in order to get 'Failed' ?
}
```

I've posted my questions on the remarks above.

Comment: you can't. you can only use angular.js to call node.js api and get the returned data using a callback.

Comment: So I need to configure the route for the login.html on my controller template ? If I do that, how can I get a callback from the server ?

Comment: yes. you should use angular to handle routings. angualr is a selfcontained mvc framework, your node.js becomes just your SOA layer.

Comment: ok, so how do I get a callback from the server ?

Comment: You're using express right?

Comment: yes. I'm using express as my app middleware

Comment: See the answer to this question, this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097244/how-to-send-backend-errors-success-messages-from-node-js-to-frontend-in-angularj